# iOS / Cordova HTML5-Video not playing

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, meteor, html5-video

My meteor / cordova app downloads videos to play them offline.

Downloading works fine. Android works fine ... But iOS not..

I tried local absolute URLs: `file:///...` but I'm getting `Not allowed to load local resource Error` so I use cordova-httpd as on Android, but this also not works, without any errors (http://127.0.0.1:8880/ oder http://192.168.2.100:8880). If I open the URL in Browser or curl I can view/download the video, so the httpd server seems to work. I tried on real iPhone and in iOS Simulator.

Playing video direct from remote/internet works.

I tried this HTML snippets:

```
 <div class="video-container">
    <video src="{{video_url}}" type="video/mp4" width="100%" controls="controls">
    </video>
    <button class="ion-play play-button"></button>
 </div>
```

and

```
 <div class="video-container">
    <video width="100%" controls="controls">
       <source src="{{video_url}}" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <button class="ion-play play-button"></button>
 </div>
```

In the last days I read so much issues on github and comments on stackoverflow, but I cant get it to work.

(btw. the video is also triggered with button click)

```
Template.Content.events({
"click .play-button": function (event) {
  // Prevent default browser form submit
  event.preventDefault();
  event.target.classList.add('playing');
  var video = event.target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
  video.load();
  video.play();
}
});
```

Please, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. My url had a double slash (http://192.168.0.100:8880//videos/some.mp4) and on iOS the HTTP-Server returned a 404 error.

solved by this
[Play video cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391086/play-video-cordova)